# web3 erroneously returning error

Tags: web3js, ganache

This is strange. My web3 script to deploy a contract seems to work, but always activates the .on('error', fcn) clause even though there is no error.

The message says **Transaction has been reverted by the EVM** but it has not really been reverted. It returns the contract address, the contract is there and I can call it with other scripts.

Code:

```
con
  .deploy({data:getBinary()} )
  .send({from: eb, gas: 1000000, gasPrice: gprice}, (err, txhash) => {
    if (txhash) console.log( "sent txhash: ", txhash );
  } )
  .on('error', (err) => { console.log("borked: ", err); })
  .on('transactionHash', (h) => { console.log( "hash: ", h ); } )
  .on('receipt', (r) => { console.log( 'rcpt: ' + r.contractAddress); } )
  .on('confirmation', (cn, rcpt) => { console.log( 'cn: ', cn ); } )
  .then( (con) => {
    console.log( "SCA", con.options.address );
    process.exit(0);
  } )
  .catch( err => { console.log } );
```

Result:

```
$ node cli.js 0 0 0 deploy
sent txhash:  0x73c25e524056d76937429a92349f019d436c452b006cb4178e4170e5b24aa5b4
hash:  0x73c25e524056d76937429a92349f019d436c452b006cb4178e4170e5b24aa5b4
borked:  Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "transactionHash": "0x73c25e524056d76937429a92349f019d436c452b006cb4178e4170e5b24aa5b4",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "blockHash": "0xa7afc701efd8fcc397536f018a3307c5d38d6031431c3887298693a9b11edfc0",
  "blockNumber": 6,
  "gasUsed": "0x0b60fa",
  "cumulativeGasUsed": "0x0b60fa",
  "contractAddress": "0x786a010206921e8ea1181d86da22adbd87259d33",
  "logs": [],
  "status": "0x01",
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "to": null
}
    at TransactionReceiptValidator.validate (/home/skull/node_modules/web3-core-method/dist/web3-core-method.cjs.js:146:16)
    at /home/skull/node_modules/web3-core-method/dist/web3-core-method.cjs.js:44:68
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

upgrade ganache-cli separately from web3 and truffle

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but I needed to upgrade Ganache 1.1.0 to 1.3.0 until I got rid of the EVM error message.